# Use of right-time-context FIWARE extension with CKAN

Tags: fiware-orion, ckan

I've managed to install the right-time-context extension to CKAN v2.8 using docker. I created a dataset for NGSI query but when I tried to create an NGSI-view I received the following error: **ngsi-proxy: 502 Bad Gateway**. Do I have to have an ngsi-proxy up and running to manage to communicate with ORION?